# How can I get a random multiple of 50 using Microsoft Small Basic?

Tags: math, random, basic, smallbasic

How can I get a random multiple of 50 between 0 and 800?

So I would need numbers:
0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,600,650,700,750,800.

I've tried using `math.getrandomnumber(800)` but that gives me any number.

Comment: What you're asking is a little unclear - do you require one of those numbers, chosen at random?

Answer (score 1):

Get a random number between `0` and `16`, then multiply it with `50`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You Should get a random number under 16. Then multiply the random number under 16 x 50. Like that you will get always a random multiple of 50 under 800. Because 50 x 16 = 800. And 16 is the maximal number that you can multiply with 50.

```
RandomNumber_under16 = Math.GetRandomNumber(16)

random_multiple_of_50_under_800 = RandomNumber_under16*50

TextWindow.WriteLine(random_multiple_of_50_under_800)
```

Comment: Provide some explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

> So I would need numbers, 0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,600,650,700,750,800

You can build these numbers by scaling the numbers in the range [0,16] by a factor of 50.

Given the definition of the `Math.GetRandomNumber` function

> `Math.GetRandomNumber(maxNumber)`
> Gets a random number between 1 and the specified maxNumber (inclusive).
> Parameters
> maxNumber: The maximum number for the requested random value.
> Returns
> A Random number that is less than or equal to the specified max.

your solution will have to account for the fact that the returned random **integer** starts at **1** whereas you need to include **0** in your list.
Next code snippet produces the desired result:

```
For i = 1 To 20
  TextWindow.WriteLine((Math.GetRandomNumber(17) - 1) * 50)
EndFor
' Math.GetRandomNumber(17)              -> [1,17]
' Math.GetRandomNumber(17) - 1          -> [0,16]
' (Math.GetRandomNumber(17) - 1) * 50   -> {0,50,100,150, ... ,800}
```